# Tawk.to chat messenger integration in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, tawk.to

I am currently stuck in implementing Tawk chat for my Vue app. I want to render it in my `HomeView` so that user can submit their messages via chat.

I have currently created a separate view for the messenger via template but unfortunately, it's not displaying once I run the app. Below is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div id="tawk-chat">
    <!-- This div will be used by Tawk to display the chat widget. -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    // Load Tawk.to script.

    const s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = 'https://tawk.to/chat/64ca9f36cc26a871b02cdf13/1h6rnrrt8';

    s.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
    s.setAttribute('defer', 'true');
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  },
};
</script>
  
<style scoped>
/* Add any custom styling for the chat widget here */
</style>
```

Here is my `HomeView`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="Hero-section">
    <div class="Hero-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h3>....</h3>
          <h2>....</h2>
          <p>
          .....
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c2a">
        <router-link to="/about">
          <button>Get Started</button>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h1>Our Solutions</h1>
  <div class="solutions">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" v-for="solution in SolutionsData" :key="solution.id">
        <div class="card">
          <img
            :src="solution.Image"
            alt="This is an image"
            height="400"
            with="300"
          />
          <h3>{{ solution.title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ solution.description }}</p>
          <div class="c2a">
            <button>Get Started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <TawkToMessenger />
</template>

<script>
import { SolutionsData } from "@/utils/SolutionsData";
import TawkToMessenger from "@/views/TawkToMessenger.vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      SolutionsData,
      TawkToMessenger
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Side comment: `<h3>....</h3> <h2>....</h2>` No. just no. That is not how headings and heading structure work. Headings are for specifying your page structure. If you want different text sizes, use CSS. Same with the "Our Solutions" section: use `h1` and `h2`, not `h1` and then `h3`.